# No such file/directory message when trying to run iOS emulator using meteor run ios

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

Im getting this error when I try to run the iOS emulator

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:  



   While running Cordova app for platform iOS with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed: /Users/paulhayes/code/microscope/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
   ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/paulhayes/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/E99C26C3-5BDD-4BBE-A63E-6510238BCC45/system.log'
   Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args:
   launch,/Users/paulhayes/code/microscope/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/build/emulator/microscope.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/paulhayes/code/microscope/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/paulhayes/code/microscope/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

ExitWithCode:1
```

I've gone through the steps outlined at https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile and I checked my Xcode installation by running a HelloWorld Swift app from xcode - it worked fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: just try  "cordova build ios" and then run the project from xcode to see if it works

Comment: when i try that I get 'cordova: command not found'.  The build seems to be working, the problem seems to be occurring when attempting to start the emulator. How would I run the project from xcode? (which directory do I open?)

Comment: Did you install Cordova if not install using npm install - g Cordova and once you will run the run command it will create a platforms folder inside which you will find Xcode project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it took me a day to find the solution. Short story -

1. Make sure you don’t have any old copy of Xcode somewhere in your system, especially check the `/Recovered\ Items/Applications/` Directory.
2. Check that you have a simulator defined in Xcode > Window > Devices with the same identifier as in the error you got, e.g. E99C26C3-5BDD-4BBE-A63E-6510238BCC45, if you don’t you need to add a matching simulator to the list, and lunch it so the directory and system.log file will be created.